# Function $y=f(x)$ having two points of discontinuity

Tags: functions, continuity

> If function $y = f(x)$ has only two points of discontinuity say $x_1, x_2$, where $x_1, x_2 < 0$, then the number of points of discontinuity of $f(-|x+1|)$  is_____

I checked this question no other information is provided, this appeared in a sample paper of a top coaching, how do we proceed

Comment: Add some information been provided i would have approached this but with no information of $y=f(x)$ how do we proceed

Comment: Why don't you guess? It's probably an even better strategy if you're given options. For example, take a function with two discontinuities, something like $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in (-3,-2)$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise (this will have discontinuities at $-3$ and $-2$ and be continuous elsewhere). What do you observe about $f(-|x+1|)$ now?

Comment: Think it through... Say the points of discontinuity are $-1$ and $-2$. For what values of $x$ will $-|x+1|$ hit one of those points of discontinuity?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin if $y=f(x)$ has two point of discontinuity then $ y=f(x+1)$ will also have two point of discontinuity but how can we infer the number of discontinuity point of $y=f(|x+1|)$